# Problem with Transpose Rows to column (Pivot) in the same table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm working on mysql database which is like this one

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcustomfieldsvalues` (
  `fieldid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relid` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `values` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and sample data like below

```
INSERT INTO `tblcustomfieldsvalues`(`fieldid`, `relid`, `values`) VALUES
('396', '1', 'willyemail@gmail.com'),
('397', '1', 'willy robertus'),
('398', '1', 'Santo Paulus'),
('396', '2', 'antoni@gmail.com'),
('397', '2', 'Antoni robertus'),
('398', '2', 'Sasa Paulus');
```

which give me something like this

[The Actual Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTfBi.png)

My Goals:

I need it transform the data transform into different column for each different fieldid

Let Say i want the fieldid 396 as **A** Column, 397 As **B** and the 398 field id as **C** column

So, the data look like this

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXaBn.png)

But i got something like this

i tried this query

```
select
relid,
case when fieldid = "396" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end as A,
case when fieldid = "397" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end as B,
case when fieldid = "398" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end as C
from tblcustomfieldsvalues
```

Almost meet my expectation, but there're a lot of null values

```
relid   A   B   C
1   willyrobertus@gmail.com (null)  (null)
1   (null)  willy robertus  (null)
1   (null)  (null)  Santo Paulus
2   antoni@gmail.com    (null)  (null)
2   (null)  Antoni robertus (null)
2   (null)  (null)  Sasa Paulus
```

Try to group them by relid i got mismatched row 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5352c/3)

Thank you Very Much

Willy

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5352c/8)**

```
select
relid,
max(case when fieldid = "396" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end) as A,
max(case when fieldid = "397" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end) as B,
max(case when fieldid = "398" then tblcustomfieldsvalues.values end) as C
from tblcustomfieldsvalues
group by relid
```

OUTPUT:

```
relid   A                       B                C
1       willyemail@gmail.com    willy robertus   Santo Paulus
2       antoni@gmail.com        Antoni robertus  Sasa Paulus
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the fast reply, 
How if i have some values that doesn't meet the select case statement, it will shows null,null,null like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/404fb8/1

How to hide the Null items, so only show results which have value for field id

Comment: @WillyRL, can you give as example for make it more clear

Comment: Its the same as previous @fa06 , could you please check this one? 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/404fb8/1

Comment: can you please add your expected output in the quesetion - your image is not clear @WillyRL

Comment: I try added empty string, and the result was messed up http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9b25f/1

how to show result only which meet the condition we've made in select statement?

Thanks